# ¿Cómo hacer una auditoría de varias tablas en una única tabla de auditoría?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en PHP y estoy con la parte de auditoria.

¿Cómo puedo hacer un trigger para 2 tablas?

En este caso 2 tablas que están relacionadas y estoy haciendo una bitácora donde tomé sólo una tabla `personas` pero quería también colocar los datos de la otra tabla que está relacionada con ella, `usuarios`.

```
CREATE TABLE `bitacorapersonas` (
  `idBitacora` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- autoincrementamos el identificador
  `Accion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `idUsuario` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `cedulaVieja` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL, -- DEFAULT para insertar sin valor inicial
  `nombreNuevo` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombreViejo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, -- DEFAULT para insertar sin valor inicial
  `apellidoNuevo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoViejo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, -- DEFAULT para insertar sin valor inicial
  `sexoNuevo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sexoViejo` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, -- DEFAULT para insertar sin valor inicial
  `telefonoNuevo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `telefonoViejo` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, -- DEFAULT para insertar sin valor inicial
  `direccionNuevo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `direccionViejo` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, -- DEFAULT para insertar sin valor inicial
  `fnacimientoNuevo` date NOT NULL,
  `fnacimientoViejo` date DEFAULT NULL, -- DEFAULT para insertar sin valor inicial
  PRIMARY KEY (idBitacora) -- Lo necesitamos para poder usar autoincrement
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_session` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dni` text NOT NULL, -- Si se quiere agregar también el DNI (según lo solicitado)
  `activacion` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
   usuarios_cedula( que es la foranea entre persona y usuarios)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` text NOT NULL,
  `fnacimiento` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TRIGGER Personas_AInsertar AFTER INSERT ON personas 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO bitacorapersonas (
  idUsuario,
  Accion,
  fecha,
  cedula,
  nombreNuevo,
  apellidoNuevo,
  sexoNuevo,
  telefonoNuevo,
  direccionNuevo,
  fnacimientoNuevo
) VALUES (
  @identificador,
  'Inserto',
  NOW(),
  NEW.cedula,
  NEW.nombres,
  NEW.apellidos,
  NEW.sexo,
  NEW.telefono,
  NEW.direccion,
  NEW.fnacimiento
);
```

A parte, ¿cómo puedo hacer el uso de dos trigger para modificar en la misma tabla?

Comment: Ya te he enviado la respuesta, voy a editarla para meter código de ejemplo para cada solución que te propongo, pero quiero confirmar que quieres guardar la bitácora de modificaciones de dos tablas en una única tabla. Si es así modifica tu pregunta para agregar ese detalle, la pregunta entiende otra cosa.

Comment: ¿Podrías comprobar si mi respuesta te sirvió para solucionar tus dudas o problemas? Si es así agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como correcta. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

**¿Cómo puedo hacer un trigger para 2 tablas?**

No puedes.

La [definición de un trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) sólo permite asociarlo a una tabla, acción (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` y `DELETE`) y momento (`BEFORE` o `AFTER`).

La única solución es crear dos triggers, uno que responda a los eventos de la primera tabla y otro que responda a los eventos de la segunda.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer el uso de dos trigger para modificar en la misma tabla?**

A partir de MySQL 5.7.2 se pueden asociar varios triggers a una misma tabla, acción y momento, pudiendo indicar el orden mediante el uso de un nuevo modificador opcional (`FOLLOWS` y `PRECEDES` a otro trigger).

Anteriormente a esa versión no es posible hacerlo, aunque hay dos soluciones que podrían paliar el problema:

- Hacer uso de `BEFORE` y `AFTER` para tener posibilidad de tener dos, aunque con la limitaciones de usar `BEFORE`.
- Modificar el trigger y concatenar en un bloque `BEGIN`/`END` todas las acciones necesarias.

---

**Soluciones propuestas:**

En la primera consulta parece que lo que deseas es crear dos triggers y que escriban datos en la misma tabla de auditoría.

Esto es posible, pero la tabla de auditoría debería modificarse para soportar guardar información que puede variar entre tabla y tabla.

Te recomiendo que para ello guardes la información en JSON dentro de un campo `antes` y `despues`. El campo `Accion` te lo puedes ahorrar ya que se deduce del contenido de `antes` y `despues`:

- `antes` es `null`: inserción.
- `despues` es `null`: borrado.
- Ni `antes` ni `despues` valen `null`: modificación.

La tabla de bitácora, por tanto, podría definirse así:

```
-- Tabla de bitacora compatible con el registro de cualquier tabla usando JSON
CREATE TABLE `bitacora` (
  `idBitacora` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datos` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `tabla` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `antes` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `despues` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idBitacora)
);
```

He eliminado la referencia en el nombre (`bitacorapersonas`) a la tabla `personas` porque ahora se guardará la tabla a la que corresponde el registro de auditoría en el campo `tabla`.

Hay una modificación que proviene del chat en el que los datos (`@datos`) del usuario se guardan también en JSON para almacenar todos los datos de éste y no sólo su identificador (`idUsuario`).

Ahora el trigger para gestionar inserciones se te quedaría así:

```
-- Trigger para introducción de registros de personas adaptado a datos JSON
CREATE TRIGGER personas_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON personas 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO bitacora (
  datos,
  tabla,
  antes,
  despues,
  fecha
) VALUES (
  @datos,
  'personas',
  null,
  JSON_OBJECT(
    'cedula', NEW.cedula,
    'nombres', NEW.nombres,
    'apellidos', NEW.apellidos,
    'sexo', NEW.sexo,
    'telefono', NEW.telefono,
    'direccion', NEW.direccion,
    'fnacimiento', NEW.fnacimiento
  ),
  NOW()
);
```

Para crear un trigger similar pero que trabaje contra la tabla `usuarios` basta con modificar ligeramente el trigger:

```
-- Trigger que para la tabla personas, pero con los datos de usuarios
CREATE TRIGGER usuarios_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON usuarios 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO bitacora (
  datos,
  tabla,
  antes,
  despues,
  fecha
) VALUES (
  @datos,
  'usuarios',
  null,
  JSON_OBJECT(
    'id', NEW.id,
    'correo', NEW.correo,
    'usuario', NEW.usuario,
    'password', NEW.password,
    'last_session', NEW.last_session,
    'dni', NEW.dni,
    'activacion', NEW.activacion,
    'usuarios_cedula', NEW.usuarios_cedula
  ),
  NOW()
);
```

El borrado (sólo de la tabla `personas`) quedaría:

```
CREATE TRIGGER personas_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON personas 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO bitacora (
  datos,
  tabla,
  antes,
  despues,
  fecha
) VALUES (
  @datos,
  'personas',
  JSON_OBJECT(
    'cedula', OLD.cedula,
    'nombres', OLD.nombres,
    'apellidos', OLD.apellidos,
    'sexo', OLD.sexo,
    'telefono', OLD.telefono,
    'direccion', OLD.direccion,
    'fnacimiento', OLD.fnacimiento
  ),
  null,
  NOW()
);
```

Y la actualización (la más completa):

```
CREATE TRIGGER personas_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON personas 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO bitacora (
  datos,
  tabla,
  antes,
  despues,
  fecha
) VALUES (
  @datos,
  'personas',
  JSON_OBJECT(
    'cedula', OLD.cedula,
    'nombres', OLD.nombres,
    'apellidos', OLD.apellidos,
    'sexo', OLD.sexo,
    'telefono', OLD.telefono,
    'direccion', OLD.direccion,
    'fnacimiento', OLD.fnacimiento
  ),
  JSON_OBJECT(
    'cedula', NEW.cedula,
    'nombres', NEW.nombres,
    'apellidos', NEW.apellidos,
    'sexo', NEW.sexo,
    'telefono', NEW.telefono,
    'direccion', NEW.direccion,
    'fnacimiento', NEW.fnacimiento
  ),
  NOW()
);
```

Con estos ejemplos podrás crear fácilmente nuevos triggers para generar auditoría en prácticamente cualquier tabla.

La sintaxis para obtener un dato de un campo de tipo `json` es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
  idBitacora,
  datos->>"$.usuario" usuario,
  tabla,
  antes,
  despues,
  fecha
FROM bitacora;
```

Como puedes observar se agrega el operador `->` (equivalente a [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)) o `->>` (`JSON_EXTRACT` más un [`JSON_UNQUOTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote)) al nombre del campo y tras él se introduce entre comillas la [ruta JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) deseada.

En el ejemplo (`"$.usuario"`) obtenemos el índice `usuario` que cuelga del elemento raíz.

Puedes ver un ejemplo online completo en: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fYMuY62pZwmhuWBZbiQGvt/1